# "Windows application packaging project" signing error

Tags: signing, desktop-bridge, appx, appxmanifest

I am bringing a WPF to the Windows store using a "Windows application packaging project" since 2 years. Until I freshly installed my development system, everything was fine (as usual). When I open the project in VS2019 and start to build the app-package in the publish section, all processes run through but it stops at package signing with "Error signing ....appx".
After checking the EventLog at "Applications and Services/Microsoft/Windows/AppxPackagingOM" there always are 4 warnings in a row with all the same ID 216 saying "app manifest validation warning declared http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/appx/2015/build-Namespace is inapplicable"
I have never experienced signing errors especially because I am not using any self signed certificate or sth like that.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

This should be a known issue, the specific discussion is [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/934967/uwp-error-failed-to-sign.html)

You can resolve this issue by uninstalling the `KB4535996` patch update.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer and the hint. For me the situation was, that KB4535996 actually was not installed, but your link lead me to discussions that helped me. My problem is addressed [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/940627/latest-update-to-windows-10-has-broken-visual-stud.html). Hopefully they will publish a fix soon!

Comment: I also look forward to the release of the new version. But if you urgently need to package your app, consider installing a lower version of Visual Studio